# Jest test fails when using window object environment variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

My tests were running fine first, I am now using environmental variables based on the window object like:

```
{window._env_.REACT_APP_URL}
```

But when I run my test: it shows as `TypeError: Cannot read property 'REACT_APP_URL' of undefined`

Do I need to do something different in my test files to accept this type of variable, when I change to `{process.env.REACT_APP_URL}` everything works as expected?

Any idea's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `_env_` property does not exist on the `window` object out of the box, hence TypeScript is complaining that you are assigning a value to an `undefined` property.

Best way to solve your issue is to reassign the `window` variable to a custom one that combines the current `window` types with your own custom `EnvironmentVariables` interface and use that in your tests instead:

```
interface EnvironmentVariables {
  '_env_': {
    'REACT_APP_URL': string
  }
}

const customWindow = window as Window & typeof globalThis & EnvironmentVariables;

// set the _env_ object with values
customWindow._env_ = {
  'REACT_APP_URL': 'url here'
}

// access REACT_APP_URL
customWindow._env_.REACT_APP_URL
```

Comment: What if the url comes from a .env file? as in where would you declare this code? in the component, different file etc?

Comment: That's a good question. The ```window``` variable should exist throughout the runtime of all tests, so if you place the code above within the suite that is going to be using ```REACT_APP_URL```, they should run as expected.
In regards to how you retrieve and assign the value for the environment variable is up to the setup of your application. If you are using ```.env``` files, it will likely be like this ```customWindow._env_ = { 'REACT_APP_URL': process.env.REACT_APP_URL }```, but that is up to your application setup and out of scope of the original question.